# What is cosmological critical density?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, gravity, space-expansion, density

I'm taking a first course in cosmology and I'm struggling to understand exactly what critical density is. I've been told "Critical density is the energy density of the universe that corresponds to the Hubble parameter measured today", but what does that really mean?

Is the critical density of the universe simply the "total" energy density, obtained via

$$\rho_{crit}=\rho_{matter}+\rho_{radiation}+\rho_{darkmatter}+\rho_{dark energy},$$

(omitting the types of energy density not present in the universe in question)?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Density_parameter

Comment: My (layman's) impression, obtained from reading verbiage, has been that the critical density, in cosmology, is that density of matter whose gravitational effect would either cause the Universe to begin collapsing, or reveal that it will never collapse:  However, these possibilities do seem to vary between 1915's General Relativity and 1929's Einstein-Cartan Theory, as the start of collapse would be associated with the Universe having a spherical shape in the older of those two Einsteinian theories, but not in the newer one, possibly because the latter  assigns a spatial extent to fermions.

Comment: As GR and ECT are both, essentially, theories of gravity that were written by Einstein (with the latter having been written by him in collaboration with the mathematician Cartan), I've added (subject to approval) a generic "gravity" tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can think critical density as a some sort of measure of the curvature.

$$H^2 = \frac{8 \pi G}{3c^2}\sum_i\varepsilon_i - \frac{\kappa c^2}{Ra^2}$$

Let us write the equation in this form,

$$H^2 - \frac{8 \pi G}{3c^2}\sum_i\varepsilon_i = - \frac{\kappa c^2}{Ra^2}~~(1)$$

For $\kappa = 0$ we need

$$H^2 - \frac{8 \pi G}{3c^2}\sum_i\varepsilon_i=0$$

Lets call  $$\sum_i\varepsilon_i = \varepsilon_{crit}$$

In this case we have

$$\varepsilon_{crit} = \frac{3c^2H^2}{8 \pi G}$$

Let us look Equation (1).

When we have a density parameter $\varepsilon_x$ such that $\varepsilon_x > \varepsilon_{crit}$ the RHS becomes negative so $\kappa$ becomes positive ($\kappa > 0$)which corresponds to positive curvature or closed universe.

When we have $\varepsilon_x < \varepsilon_{crit}$ the RHS becomes positive which corresponds to negative kappa ($\kappa < 0$) which describes negative curvature.

Comment: Re my comments on the question, the ECT model I've mentioned is Nikodem Poplawski's torsion-based multiverse, detailed in 2010-2021 papers whose preprints are freely visible on the << Arxiv >> website:  He has analogized the local universes (including our own) of his "indefinitely expanding" model to the skin of a basketball, although none of any LU's occupants would, of course, be able to see its shape from the outside.  A basketball's geometry's not negatively curved (i.e., anlogized as "hyperbolic" or "saddle-shaped"). I'll edit in a GR tag later, but...any clarifying opinions on this?

Comment: I think I've demonstrated the need for an "Einstein-Cartan" tag, but lack the rep to add one.

Comment: Re ECT, I should point out the fact that, as pointed out by Rutgers University's Daniel Lindford (in a paper titled "Big Bounce or Double Bang" that's freely visible online), Poplawski's model is past- and future-eternal and, consequently, may run afoul of creationistic beliefs prevalent in much of the United States, and influential in that country's system of private and state-run universities.

Comment: In fairness, I should add that, since France, a country whose percentage of "unbelievers" is usually estimated at @70%, it's surprising to find how little ECT is mentioned in French pop-sci media, especially given the fact that two of Cartan's sons have long remained significant mathematicians there: This, together with a comment or two from physicists on PSE, has led me (an interpreter) to consider ECT as more subtle than GR. But who (or Who) said understanding the universe (or the multiverse, if it is one) would be easy?

Comment: Plainly, if it was easy to understand, beings not unlike ourselves would have destroyed it by now, for no valid reason at all.

Comment: As SevenVo1D's answer was written only in the context of GR, and my edit's intended to put the OP's question into the broader context of "theories of gravity" in general, I found an extremely plausible answer (to a different PSE question) that SevenVo1D had answered on an earlier occasion, and upvoted it so as to avoid the unjustified damage to his reputation that such placement of the OP's question into a more general context of gravitational theory might otherwise have caused.